# How to do this with Databinding

Tags: c#, data-binding

Here's a function to populate a combobox with `SaveState.SaveName` values. As you can see I'm not using `ItemsSource` I'm looking for a better way to do this function.

```
public void RestoreState(List<SaveState> names)
{
    foreach (SaveState st in names)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Content = st.SaveName;
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add(l); 
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
this.comboBox1.ItemsSource = names;
```

But the combobox was populated with my datatype.  Can I use the ItemsSource in such a way that it populates the combobox with the data member "SaveName"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.comboBox1.ItemSource = names.Select(o=>o.SaveName)
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
this.comboBox1.DataSource = names;
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "SaveName";
```